MySQL C++ connector undefined reference on Windows, MinGW compiler
I am new to C++ connector with MySQL, I have tried many ways to link C++ with MySQL but none of them was successfully compiled. The C++ code is:
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <jdbc.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
    sql::Driver *driver = get_driver_instance();
    sql::Connection *con = driver->connect("localhost:3306", "root", "root");
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;

    con->setSchema("company");
}

The CMakeLists.txt file is:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(CQL)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(CQL main.cpp)

add_compile_options(
        -lmariadbcpp
        -lmysqlcppconn)

include_directories("C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysql"
        "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/mysqlx"
        "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc"
        "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include"
        "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0"
        "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/bin"
)

target_link_directories(CQL PUBLIC "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0")
target_link_directories(CQL PUBLIC "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/lib64")
target_link_directories(CQL PUBLIC "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/lib64/plugin")
target_link_directories(CQL PUBLIC "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/lib64/vs14")
target_link_directories(CQL PUBLIC "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/lib64/bin")
link_directories("C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0")
link_directories("C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/lib64")
link_directories("C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/lib64/plugin")
link_directories("C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/lib64/vs14")
link_directories("C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/bin")

A part of the error is:
[2/2] Linking CXX executable CQL.exe
FAILED: CQL.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\c++.exe -g  CMakeFiles/CQL.dir/main.cpp.obj -o CQL.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libCQL.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -LC:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/CONNEC~2.0   -LC:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/CONNEC~2.0/lib64   -LC:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/CONNEC~2.0/lib64/plugin   -LC:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/CONNEC~2.0/lib64/vs14   -L"C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/lib64/bin" -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/CQL.dir/main.cpp.obj: in function `check_lib':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:82:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `check(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:83:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `check(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/CQL.dir/main.cpp.obj: in function `get_driver_instance_by_name':
C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include/jdbc/cppconn/driver.h:95:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `_get_driver_instance_by_name'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

My comment:

I think the add_compile_options looks useless because they don't even appear on the compile command.
I use windows 11
This is the MySQL connector for windows 64bit x86, I use os is windows 64bit x64, can that cause any problem? There is not a MySQL connector for windows 64bit x64 at the time I download MySQL connector.
I find most of the solution to this problem is for linux.

SOLUTION
As @drescherjm suggested in the comment, and for my knowledge, there is no solution to use a MinGW compiler, switch to Linux or MSVC will solve.

I believe your problem is you installed the msvc binaries and not ones for MinGW. C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/lib64/vs14" are compiled for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and not MinGW.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67344501/mysql-and-mariadb-librarys-in-c-using-cmake-mingw
