Linker Error with MariaDB Connector/C++ When Using CMake
I'm encountering a linker error while trying to build a project using the MariaDB Connector/C++ 1.1.4 on Windows with CMake. I installed the MariaDB Connector/C++ from the MariaDB download page and set up my CMake project as follows:
CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(MariaDB_Connector_Sample)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(MariaDB_Connector_Sample main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(MariaDB_Connector_Sample PUBLIC
    "C:/Program Files/MariaDB/MariaDB C++ Connector 64-bit/mariadbcpp.lib"
)

target_include_directories(MariaDB_Connector_Sample PUBLIC
    "C:/Program Files/MariaDB/MariaDB C++ Connector 64-bit/include"
)

main.cpp:
#include <mariadb/conncpp.hpp>

int main()
{
    auto driver = sql::mariadb::get_driver_instance();
    return 0;
}

Error Message:
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MariaDB_Connector_Sample.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable MariaDB_Connector_Sample.exe
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\MariaDB_Connector_Sample.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xa): undefined reference to `sql::mariadb::get_driver_instance()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\MariaDB_Connector_Sample.dir\build.make:100: MariaDB_Connector_Sample.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/MariaDB_Connector_Sample.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:89: CMakeFiles/MariaDB_Connector_Sample.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:123: MariaDB_Connector_Sample] Error 2

I configured my CMake project to use the MariaDB Connector/C++ 1.1.4 by specifying the library and include paths directly. I then built the project using MinGW and CMake. I expected the project to compile and link successfully, resulting in an executable that utilizes the MariaDB Connector/C++ library. Instead, I received a linker error indicating an undefined reference to sql::mariadb::get_driver_instance(). This suggests that the linker cannot find the definition of the function provided by the MariaDB Connector/C++ library.

I expect the official Windows download is for msvc only and won't work with MinGW just like the MySQL connector.

At least one answer for question from 2021 says my above comment was correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67344501/mysql-and-mariadb-librarys-in-c-using-cmake-mingw

MariaDB Connector/C, C++ and ODBC are build with MSVC (Visual Studio).
While it's possible (with several limitations) to link a MSVC C library under MingW, this is not possible for C++ libraries.
If you want to use MariaDB Connector/C++ under mingw, you have to build MariaDB Connector/C++ from source. Msys2 doesn't offer a C++ package for MariaDB (only C). MinGW is not an officially supported platform for MariaDB products, so cross your finger that it will build.

Thank you for answer, it's working when I compile from the source.
