Connecting MYSQL to C++ using Cmake
I want to build a C++ program that creates users and saves them to a DB (mysql). I am using Cmake to compile and VSCode as IDE. I have installed MYSQL, MYSQL C++ Connector. However my IDE says #include <mysql/cppconn> ... cannot open source file.
This is my header file for database class:
#ifndef DATABASE_HPP
#define DATABASE_HPP

#include <mysql_driver.h>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Database {
public:
    // Constructor to initialize database connection
    Database();

    // Method to add a new account to the database
    void AddAccount(int accountID, const std::string& name, double balance, const std::string& password);

    // Method to update the account balance after a transaction
    void UpdateBalance(int accountID, double new_balance);

private:
    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
    std::unique_ptr<sql::Connection> con;
};

#endif

This is my root directory CmakeLists.txt file:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25.0)

set(This Castle)

project(${This} C CXX)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

# Enable testing
enable_testing()

# Add GoogleTest subdirectory
add_subdirectory(googletest)

# Include directory for your headers
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

# Find OpenSSL package (make sure OpenSSL is installed and the path is correct)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})

# Find MySQL Connector/C++ package
include_directories("C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 9.0/include/mysql")
link_directories("C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 9.0/lib64")

# Include MySQL Connector/C++ directories
include_directories(${MYSQLCONNECTORCPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Your source and header files
set(Headers
    include/account.hpp
    include/security.hpp
    include/transaction.hpp
    include/auditLog.hpp
)

set(Sources
    src/account.cpp
    src/security.cpp
    src/transaction.cpp
    src/auditLog.cpp
)

# Create a static library
add_library(${This} STATIC ${Sources} ${Headers})

# Link OpenSSL and MySQL Connector libraries to your static library
target_link_libraries(${This} PUBLIC OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto ${MYSQLCONNECTORCPP_LIBRARIES})

# Add subdirectory for tests
add_subdirectory(tests)

I made sure that my path to MYSQL C++ Connector includes the mysql_driver.h, cppconn directory and other necessary header files, yet it still won't work.
Thanks in advance for the help.

That include_directories statement should stop at include, not include/mysql.

Also, recent version of the C++ connector seem to ship with a nice imported target by default

OT: . I am using Cmake to compile and VSCode as IDE. I have installed MYSQL, MYSQL C++ Connector. Are you using msvc for your compiler? Remember the download is for msvc and it will not work for MinGW. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67344501/mysql-and-mariadb-librarys-in-c-using-cmake-mingw

As of version 8.3.0, the MySQL Connector ships with a nice set of CMake targets you link to:
set(mysql-concpp_DIR "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 9.0")
find_package(mysql-concpp REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${This} PUBLIC mysql::concpp)

